# After enable rules of ipfw my server collapsed

Tags: freebsd, swap, ipfw

I enable  ipfw rules on my mail server. After some time server collapsed. In /var/log/messages  is nothing information of my damage. But when I connected monitor, I saw some troubles with swap

```
swap_pager: indefinite wait buffer
```

Then I entered command dmesg and saw:

```
total configured swap (1048576 pages) exceeds maximum recommended amount (980224 pages).
 increase kern.maxswzone or reduce amount of swap.
```

What I must do?
Increase kern.maxswzone? Or increase RAM? Or increase swap?

Сan this problem be due ipfw?
Before ipfw everything worked.
RAM on server - 512 Mb.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your machine architecture and version of FreeBSD.  `uname -a` will give you that.  My first suggestion would be to increase the RAM.  What is the approximate level of complexity of your firewall rules ... what's the output of `ipfw list | wc -l`?  The `swap_pager` error message suggests you may have hardware problems in your disk subsystem ... failing disk, bad sectors in the swap partition, bad cabling?

Comment: See [Swap "kern.maxswzone" Help](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/swap-kern-maxswzone-help.43107/) "... They recommended setting it to 0 to let it choose it's own amount automatically. ... Note that this is only if you were using amd64. If you are using i386 then I think it needs setting properly. With i386 I think it has issues using approx 4GB or more swap."

Comment: Result of uname -a FreeBSD mail.domain.com 10.3-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE #0 r297264: Fri Mar 25 03:51:29 UTC 2016     root@releng1.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  i386

Comment: my firewall rules https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/980247/308859